# How to increase the popup size of ReSharper?

Tags: resharper

ReSharper's popups (such as the one from Refactor) are always extremely small and I **always** resize them to be able to see something. I could not find a setting for this in the interface, is there perhaps a hidden setting to at least increase the size of the popup by a factor 4-5? It's highly frustrating that they still think people run screens of 640x480 (at least it seems to be suited to them).

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, the initial sizes can't be changed, and they don't remember the last size, either. I've created a [feature request](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-425750) that you can vote on and track. It would be useful to add any information such as examples of which popups you mean, and if you're using high DPI or not.